# RuntimeError: mean is not implemented for type torch.ByteTensor

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I am getting this error after running my code:
"RuntimeError: mean is not implemented for type torch.ByteTensor"?
Do anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

`accuracy = torch.mean(output)`

Answer (score 1):

Got it, basically torch.mean() isn't implemented on torch.ByteTensor so we can convert it to FloatTensor which is supported by torch.mean().
So the code will change to:

`accuracy = torch.mean(output.type(torch.FloatTensor))`